# updating data from one to table to another table which are in two different schema

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I got two schema A and B. In A there is a table 'company' and in B there is a table 'newcompany'. Now I need all the data which is residing on A.company to be updated on B.newcompany whenever there is some data updation on A.company.

Please help me out with a query or some function which implements this functionality.

Comment: You'll want to look at triggers.  They are pieces of code that can be designed to execute when data is inserted, updated or deleted.

Comment: Triggers.. Triggers.. Triggers... But they are the best when avoided unless you need the data updated in real time.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate data in two different tables in the same database?  That very rarely makes sense.  It generally makes much more sense to replace `b.newcompany` with a view or to create a table in `B` that is a child of `a.company` or to replace `a.company` with a view that queries `b.newcompany`.

Comment: thanks for the response. can you guys help me with a sample query using the names i mentioned ?

Comment: I need to duplicate it because i am adding few new columns to B.newcompany and those columns should not be added to A.company.

Comment: Are these columns computable from other columns or not?

Answer (score 0):

You could give grants to the user and simply access the table as B.newcompany inside an onupdate trigger for the A.company table.